# Google Authenticator for Salesforce 2FA

Tags: two-factor-authentication

I can successfully use the Salesforce Authenticator 2FA.  However, my users currently use the Google Authenticator for other applications and would also like to use it for Salesforce.  Are there instructions for how to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Under "Set Up Two-Factor Authentication" Salesforce has a section called "[Verify Your Identitiy with a One-Time Password Generator App or Device](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=add_time-based_token.htm&type=5)"

1. In Salesforce, go to your personal settings, *Advanced User Details* or *Personal Information*.
2. Go to *Registration: One-Time Password Generator* and click *Connect*. (You specifically want this setting because you would *not* be using Salesforce Authenticator)
3. You'll be prompted to log in for security.
4. Use Google Authenticator to take a picture of the generated QR code.
5. Verify the setup by entering your first generated password in the *Verification Code* field.
6. Click Connect.

Comment: Worked great!  Thank you!